# Formato JSON cargar DataTable

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, typescript, datatables

Importe un archivo Excel de 47 columnas y 6,190 registros, lo convertir a formato JSON para cargar un DataTable. El tema es que solo quiero cargar 11 columnas del Excel al Datatable en este orden [9, 17, 18, 24, 25, 44, 45, 20, 21, 22, 2]. Con el código anterior que cargaba por completo todas las columnas conseguí cargar el Datatable, pero como la idea es solo cargar 11 columnas estoy implementado un filtrado para poder car solo 11 columnas, conseguí que se cargara el paginado, además las filas del Datatable también se muestra como esta predeterminado en 8 filas, pero el problema es que no se visualizan los registros.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- DataTable -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Bootstrap-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Biblioteca XLSX para la manipulación de archivos Excel -->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.3/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <title>Tasa de Servicio por Centro de Distribucion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".xls,.xlsx" /><br />
    <div class="container my-5">
      <div class="row">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%">
          <caption>
            Ejemplo de DataTable
          </caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
          <th>Almacen</th>
              <th>Articulo</th>
              <th>Descripcion</th>
              <th>Stock</th>
              <th>InventAsig</th>
              <th>Reserva</th>
              <th>Transito</th>
              <th>Ord</th>
              <th>Asig</th>
              <th>Pick</th>
              <th>FaltPick</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="table_users"></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <!-- DataTable -->
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"
    ></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="./excel-json.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
let dataTable;
let dataTableIsInitialized = false;

let dataTableOptions = {
  dom: 'Bfrtilp',
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
      titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
      className: 'btn btn-success',
    },
    {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
      titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
      className: 'btn btn-danger',
    },
    {
      extend: 'print',
      text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
      titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
      className: 'btn btn-info',
    },
  ],
columnDefs: [
    { className: 'centered', targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] },
    { orderable: false, targets: [2] },
    { searchable: false, targets: [1] },
    { width: '20%', targets: [1] },
  ],
pageLength: 8,
  destroy: true,
  language: {
    processing: 'Procesando...',
    lengthMenu: 'Mostrar _MENU_ registros',
    zeroRecords: 'No se encontraron resultados',
    emptyTable: 'Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla',
    infoEmpty: 'Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros',
    infoFiltered: '(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)',
    search: 'Buscar:',
    infoThousands: ',',
    loadingRecords: 'Cargando...',
    paginate: {
      first: 'Primero',
      last: 'Último',
      next: 'Siguiente',
      previous: 'Anterior',
    },
    aria: {
      sortAscending: ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente',
      sortDescending: ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente',
    },
    buttons: {
      copy: 'Copiar',
      colvis: 'Visibilidad',
      collection: 'Colección',
      colvisRestore: 'Restaurar visibilidad',
      copyKeys:
        'Presione ctrl o u2318 + C para copiar los datos de la tabla al portapapeles del sistema. <br /> <br /> Para cancelar, haga clic en este mensaje o presione escape.',
      copySuccess: {
        1: 'Copiada 1 fila al portapapeles',
        _: 'Copiadas %ds fila al portapapeles',
      },
      copyTitle: 'Copiar al portapapeles',
      csv: 'CSV',
      excel: 'Excel',
      pageLength: {
        '-1': 'Mostrar todas las filas',
        _: 'Mostrar %d filas',
      },
      pdf: 'PDF',
      print: 'Imprimir',
      renameState: 'Cambiar nombre',
      updateState: 'Actualizar',
      createState: 'Crear Estado',
      removeAllStates: 'Remover Estados',
      removeState: 'Remover',
      savedStates: 'Estados Guardados',
      stateRestore: 'Estado %d',
    },
    autoFill: {
      cancel: 'Cancelar',
      fill: 'Rellene todas las celdas con <i>%d</i>',
      fillHorizontal: 'Rellenar celdas horizontalmente',
      fillVertical: 'Rellenar celdas verticalmentemente',
    },
    decimal: ',',
    searchBuilder: {
      add: 'Añadir condición',
      button: {
        0: 'Constructor de búsqueda',
        _: 'Constructor de búsqueda (%d)',
      },
      clearAll: 'Borrar todo',
      condition: 'Condición',
      conditions: {
        date: {
          after: 'Despues',
          before: 'Antes',
          between: 'Entre',
          empty: 'Vacío',
          equals: 'Igual a',
          notBetween: 'No entre',
          notEmpty: 'No Vacio',
          not: 'Diferente de',
        },
        number: {
          between: 'Entre',
          empty: 'Vacio',
          equals: 'Igual a',
          gt: 'Mayor a',
          gte: 'Mayor o igual a',
          lt: 'Menor que',
          lte: 'Menor o igual que',
          notBetween: 'No entre',
          notEmpty: 'No vacío',
          not: 'Diferente de',
        },
        string: {
          contains: 'Contiene',
          empty: 'Vacío',
          endsWith: 'Termina en',
          equals: 'Igual a',
          notEmpty: 'No Vacio',
          startsWith: 'Empieza con',
          not: 'Diferente de',
          notContains: 'No Contiene',
          notStartsWith: 'No empieza con',
          notEndsWith: 'No termina con',
        },
        array: {
          not: 'Diferente de',
          equals: 'Igual',
          empty: 'Vacío',
          contains: 'Contiene',
          notEmpty: 'No Vacío',
          without: 'Sin',
        },
      },
      data: 'Data',
      deleteTitle: 'Eliminar regla de filtrado',
      leftTitle: 'Criterios anulados',
      logicAnd: 'Y',
      logicOr: 'O',
      rightTitle: 'Criterios de sangría',
      title: {
        0: 'Constructor de búsqueda',
        _: 'Constructor de búsqueda (%d)',
      },
      value: 'Valor',
    },
    searchPanes: {
      clearMessage: 'Borrar todo',
      collapse: {
        0: 'Paneles de búsqueda',
        _: 'Paneles de búsqueda (%d)',
      },
      count: '{total}',
      countFiltered: '{shown} ({total})',
      emptyPanes: 'Sin paneles de búsqueda',
      loadMessage: 'Cargando paneles de búsqueda',
      title: 'Filtros Activos - %d',
      showMessage: 'Mostrar Todo',
      collapseMessage: 'Colapsar Todo',
    },
    select: {
      cells: {
        1: '1 celda seleccionada',
        _: '%d celdas seleccionadas',
      },
      columns: {
        1: '1 columna seleccionada',
        _: '%d columnas seleccionadas',
      },
      rows: {
        1: '1 fila seleccionada',
        _: '%d filas seleccionadas',
      },
    },
    thousands: '.',
    datetime: {
      previous: 'Anterior',
      next: 'Proximo',
      hours: 'Horas',
      minutes: 'Minutos',
      seconds: 'Segundos',
      unknown: '-',
      amPm: ['AM', 'PM'],
      months: {
        0: 'Enero',
        1: 'Febrero',
        10: 'Noviembre',
        11: 'Diciembre',
        2: 'Marzo',
        3: 'Abril',
        4: 'Mayo',
        5: 'Junio',
        6: 'Julio',
        7: 'Agosto',
        8: 'Septiembre',
        9: 'Octubre',
      },
      weekdays: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
    },
    editor: {
      close: 'Cerrar',
      create: {
        button: 'Nuevo',
        title: 'Crear Nuevo Registro',
        submit: 'Crear',
      },
      edit: {
        button: 'Editar',
        title: 'Editar Registro',
        submit: 'Actualizar',
      },
      remove: {
        button: 'Eliminar',
        title: 'Eliminar Registro',
        submit: 'Eliminar',
        confirm: {
          _: '¿Está seguro que desea eliminar %d filas?',
          1: '¿Está seguro que desea eliminar 1 fila?',
        },
      },
      error: {
        system:
          'Ha ocurrido un error en el sistema (<a target="\\" rel="\\ nofollow" href="\\">Más información&lt;\\/a&gt;).</a>',
      },
      multi: {
        title: 'Múltiples Valores',
        info: 'Los elementos seleccionados contienen diferentes valores para este registro. Para editar y establecer todos los elementos de este registro con el mismo valor, hacer click o tap aquí, de lo contrario conservarán sus valores individuales.',
        restore: 'Deshacer Cambios',
        noMulti:
          'Este registro puede ser editado individualmente, pero no como parte de un grupo.',
      },
    },
    info: 'Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros',
    stateRestore: {
      creationModal: {
        button: 'Crear',
        name: 'Nombre:',
        order: 'Clasificación',
        paging: 'Paginación',
        search: 'Busqueda',
        select: 'Seleccionar',
        columns: {
          search: 'Búsqueda de Columna',
          visible: 'Visibilidad de Columna',
        },
        title: 'Crear Nuevo Estado',
        toggleLabel: 'Incluir:',
      },
      emptyError: 'El nombre no puede estar vacio',
      removeConfirm: '¿Seguro que quiere eliminar este %s?',
      removeError: 'Error al eliminar el registro',
      removeJoiner: 'y',
      removeSubmit: 'Eliminar',
      renameButton: 'Cambiar Nombre',
      renameLabel: 'Nuevo nombre para %s',
      duplicateError: 'Ya existe un Estado con este nombre.',
      emptyStates: 'No hay Estados guardados',
      removeTitle: 'Remover Estado',
      renameTitle: 'Cambiar Nombre Estado',
    },
  },
};

// Esta función inicializa el DataTable con las opciones especificadas en 'dataTableOptions'.
// Selecciona el elemento con el id "example" y crea el DataTable con las opciones en 'dataTableOptions'.
const initDataTable = () => {
  //console.log("initDataTable");
  dataTable = $('#example').DataTable(dataTableOptions);
};

const loadJsonDataToDataTable = (jsonData) => {
  if (!jsonData || jsonData.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Cargando datos al DataTable..."); // Agregado: Para verificar si se cargan los datos
  console.log(jsonData);
  // Limpiar el DataTable antes de cargar nuevos datos.
  dataTable.clear().draw();

  // Agregar los registros al DataTable iterando por cada objeto en jsonData.
  jsonData.forEach((data) => {
    // Verificar si la columna Almacén está vacía.
    if (data[9] !== "") {
    // Convertir el objeto de datos a un array con las columnas seleccionadas en el orden deseado.
    //console.log(data);
    const rowData = [
      data[9],
      data[17],
      data[18],
      data[24],
      data[25],
      data[44],
      data[45],
      data[20],
      data[21],
      data[22],
      data[2]
    ];
  
    // Convertir el array a formato JSON con comillas dobles y luego analizarlo para asegurar el formato JSON válido.
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(rowData);
    const jsonDataParsed = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
    // Agregar el objeto jsonDataParsed directamente como una nueva fila al DataTable.
    dataTable.row.add(jsonDataParsed).draw();
  }
  });
};

document.getElementById("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  // Obtener el archivo seleccionado del input file.
  const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

  // Verificar si se seleccionó un archivo.
  if (selectedFile) {
    // Crear un nuevo objeto FileReader.
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    // Definir la función de callback para cuando el archivo se haya leído completamente.
    fileReader.onload = function (event) {
      // Obtener los datos del archivo leído como una cadena binaria.
      var data = event.target.result;
      
      // Leer el archivo como un libro de Excel usando la biblioteca XLSX.
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary" });

      var jsonData = [];

      // Iterar a través de cada hoja del libro de Excel.
      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
        // Convertir la hoja actual a un array de objetos JSON y agregarlo a jsonData usando el operador spread (...)
        var rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
        jsonData.push(...rowObject);
      });
      //console.log(jsonData);
      // Llamar a la función para cargar los datos al DataTable con el JSON obtenido del archivo Excel.
      loadJsonDataToDataTable(jsonData);
    };

    // Leer el archivo seleccionado como una cadena binaria para poder procesarlo con la biblioteca XLSX.
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
  }
});

// Ejecutar la función initDataTable al cargar la página para inicializar el DataTable.
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  initDataTable();
});
```

Comment: Pasa que tu no quieres participar en el sitio, solo quieres tus respuestas. Llevas una serie de preguntas relacionada con lo mismo y no votas ni aceptas ninguna respuesta.

Comment: Dame tu opinión sobre el tema para revisarlo, así dar aceptación y votar. Además, en algunas que he preguntado que aquí no conseguí la ayuda especifica igual conseguí darle solución y lo publique aquí mismo dando respuesta que ya logre solucionar.

Comment: Estimado pasa que el sitio es de preguntas y respuesta, no es de ayuda y soluciones. Tu puedes aprovechar esto realizando una pregunta a partir de un problema que tu tengas (pero es otro asunto). Tu has decidido participar en el sitio activamente en el último tiempo realizando preguntas, con lo cual adquieres responsabilidades. La primera es que tus preguntas sean aceptables (esto los has cumplido), luego tienes que responder los comentarios sobre las dudas que pueden surgir de tus preguntas.

Comment: Y si obtienes una respuesta que te ha ayuda a resolver el problema debes aceptarla (y ahí termina tu responsabilidad). Y si por algún motivo la respuesta no responde tu pregunta, es de buena educación indicar que no lo ha sido al autor de la misma. Así el autor puede corregir. En tu caso particular me consta que han habido respuestas que te han ayudado, ya que progresivamente en tus nuevas preguntas agregas código de las respuestas anteriores

Comment: La respuesta que deberías aceptar es la que te ayudó a resolver el problema a ti, la cual no es necesariamente la mejor de todas las respuestas que has recibido. Adicionalmente (cuando tengas la reputación necesaria) puedes votar cada una de las respuesta (o no) según los criterios de votación. Yo en lo personal considero que votar positivo a las respuestas que te han brindado (siempre que sean correctas) es de buena educación, es un pequeño acto de agradecimiento que a ti no te cuesta nada realizar

Comment: Por último, si tu has resuelto tu problema solo (sin ayuda de las otras respuesta) puedes generar tu propia respuesta y aceptarla (después de algunos días) y así otros que tengan el mismo problema se benefician. Evidentemente la respuesta debe ser distinta en esencia a las otras respuestas, cambiar un par de líneas irrelevante de código que solo funcionan a tu caso particular no  aportan nada